# multi-threading in java to process a number of tasks using a fix number of thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

I am just trying to learn more about threading. I am trying to create an application which can process 10,000 task (for example messages) using 10 thread.

previously I was trying to create a thread for each task but it's giving "Out of memory" exception.

can any please tell me how I can achieve this ? and precess 10,000 messages using 10 thread and avoid any "Out of memory" exception?

**Sorry I dont have the demo code available, so I cannot upload the sample code**

Comment: just search for `java ExecutorService`

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Fixed Thread Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) of 10 threads which you instantiate by calling

```
ExecutorService pool = ExecutoService.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Then run your threads by calling (10000 times) `execute` on the pool

```
pool.execute(new Runnable() {

     public void run() { //do stuff }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.if u want to return value ,you can use future object .if you are using java version below 8 .then use Callable anonymous class instead lambda expression

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Future<Integer> future = null;
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000 ; i++) {
            int counter = i;
            try {
                future = executorService.submit(() -> {
                    System.out.println("hello i am process :"+counter +";Thread Id "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
                    return 1;
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        executorService.shutdown();
    }
    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Comment: Your solution shows how to submit a task and get a `Future`, but the Future is not used anywhere.

Comment: you can remove future object.no need it for this.but if you want to return something from thread this is an one way.thats why i added it

Comment: Right, but in what sense has a value been "returned" if nobody ever calls `future.get()`?

Comment: this is just a hint .for some one who is looking for return values from threads .bcz some cases it need return values.for this example that part no need at all